# How to avoid strings in an ajax call for URL?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I am using ASP.Net MVC and when I want to call information in jquery / typescript I normaly do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: **MYURLHERE**,
        data: **MYDATAHERE**,
        type: "POST",
    }).done(function (data)
    {
 **DOSMT HERE**
    });
```

So basicly I call a URL from my controller to get data - very simple.
What's bothering me is the string type in the URL, so my problems are:

- When my controller method changes, I can't see the forgotten rename of the clientside in typescript while compiling (only with the runtimeerror)
- When writing code, I can't see which methods are available in my backend, I jsut have to look each time in the code or just now it (no intellisense)
- I can't make a search for used methods with "find all refernces", because its just a string...

Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: I think you can't do anything with this. You have to change the client side code when there is a change in the controller method. For verification, better you can use a REST client like postman to verify the URL is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Integration with JavaScript and server-side code has been always challenging. There are few tricks that I normally use -

- Use `Html.IdFor` to generate a strongly-typed property name. E.g. `$("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.FirstName)").val()`
- Use `Url.Action` to generate strongly-typed URL for Action Method. E.g. `$.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', ...});`
- Use `Url.Content` to generate strongly-typed URL. E.g. `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Logo.png")" alt="My Company"/>`
- Most of the time, [JetBrain's Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can detect those errors inside Views. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- Last but not least, Integration Tests with Selenium Web Driver before manual test.